# Cascade Delete, same table, Entity Framework 4 Code First

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

Hi Im currently working with .sdf database (Server Compact Version 4.0) and sql express. I'm trying to setup a cascade delete on a same table (category - sub category) but I get that I cant add relation to the same table.

> A foreign key constraint had and
>   update or a delete cascade rule, and
>   self-references a column in the same
>   table, is not allowed

What can I do about this?

**EDIT**
I'm the only one with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As your SQLException suggested, this is a limitation of SQL Server in general and has nothing to do with EF or Code First. Basically, SQL Server does not allow creating cascade actions on *Inner relationships* – when the cascade path goes from column col1 in table A to column col2 also in table A. A->A.

In fact, Code First was trying to use [Declarative Referential Integrity (DRI)](http://www.nerdymusings.com/LPMArticle.asp?ID=34) to enforce cascade deletes and SQL Server throws.

The only way to enforce cascade deletes for this relationship is to use Triggers. You can write a Delete Trigger on the category table that either deletes the dependent rows or sets all corresponding foreign keys to NULL (based on your requirements).