# Entity Framework code-first, One to Many, optional Parent on the child, cascade delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I have...

A basic definition of a 'category'

```
public abstract class BaseCategory
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; protected set; }

    public virtual List<BaseCategory> Subcategories { get; protected set; }

    public virtual BaseCategory ParentCategory { get; protected set; }

    public Guid? ParentCategoryId { get; protected set; }

    public BaseCategory(Guid id, BaseCategory parentCategory = null)
    {
        this.Id = id;

        if (parentCategory != null)
        {
            this.ParentCategory = parentCategory;
            this.ParentCategory.Subcategories.Add(this);
        }

        this.Subcategories = new List<BaseCategory>();
    }

    protected BaseCategory()
    {
    }
}
```

There is a 'user' category, which can be created by the user. It automatically gets assigned a new random guid. It **requires** to be a child of any other category.

```
public class UserCategory : BaseCategory
{
    public UserCategory(BaseCategory parentCategory) : base(Guid.NewGuid(), parentCategory)
    {
        // The user created category always needs a parent (i.e. users cannot create new top-level categories.
        if (parentCategory == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("parentCategory");
        }
    }

    protected UserCategory()
    {
    }
}
```

There is also a System-Defined category. It may or may not have a parent (i.e. it can be a 'root' category, without a parent). However, if it has a parent, the parent must be a system-defined category.

```
public class SystemCategory : BaseCategory
{
    public SystemCategory(Guid id, SystemCategory parentCategory = null) : base(id, displayName, parentCategory)
    {
    }

    protected SystemCategory()
    {
    }
}
```

In other words, I will first build a tree of a System-Defined categories (hierarchy) and then the user can 'customize' it by adding User-Category leafs to the tree.

I want when one Category is deleted, the sub-categories to be removed as well - cascade delete. Note, however, that because of the base abstract class, the relation between the objects is optional (the User Category enforces having a parent in the code, not in the database).

I understand I have to use Fluent API to configure this. I've tried this:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<BaseCategory>()
                .HasOptional(a => a.ParentCategory)
                .WithMany(a => a.Subcategories)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

but when I remove a category with a child, I get:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException:
>   System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A foreign key constraint that
>   has an UPDATE or a DELETE CASCADE rule, and self-references a column
>   in the same table, is not allowed. [ Constraint name =
>   FK_dbo.BaseCategories_dbo.BaseCategories_ParentCategoryId ].

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cascade Delete, same table, Entity Framework 4 Code First](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929611/cascade-delete-same-table-entity-framework-4-code-first)

Comment: I can't have cascade delete on the same table??